# how to set checkpiont dir PySpark Data Science Experience

Tags: pyspark, data-science-experience

Could you help me with instructions on how to set the checkpoint dir for a PySpark session on IBM's Data Science Experience?.

The need came because i have to run `connectedComponents()` from GraphFrames and it raises the following error

```java
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o221.run.
: java.io.IOException: Checkpoint directory is not set. Please set it first using sc.setCheckpointDir().
```

Comment: Have you tried `sc.setCheckpointDir()`? The error message is pretty clear about that, isn't it?

Comment: yes, however I did not know which specific directory should I put.

Answer (score 10):

The main issue is to get the directory that the notebook has as working directory to set the checkpoit dir with `sc.setCheckpointDir()`. this can be done easily with

```
!pwd
```

Then, a directory for checkpoints should be created on that route

```
!mkdir <pwd_output>/checkpoints
```

Finally set the checkpoint

```py
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('<pwd_output>/checkpoints')
```